# Module gets locked if it contains __DATA__

Tags: perl

I have a main module which imports other modules and launches an application, then it exits. While the application is opened, it locks one of the imported modules which contains `__DATA__` at the end.

**main.pm**

```
use core::test;
system("start notepad");
```

**core/test.pm**

```
package core::test;

1;
__DATA__
dummy
```

If I remove the `__DATA__` section, the module is no longer locked by the opened notepad process.

I'm using `ActivePerl 5163`.

Why is it happening and how could I fix this behaviour to don't have locked modules?

Comment: @Corion I saw that removing it solves the problem. But do you have an explanation why it behaves like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `notepad.exe` but Perl that keeps a `*DATA` filehandle open. You have to either remove the `__DATA__` section or explicitly `close *core::test::DATA` if you don't want it kept open/locked.

Perl holds the file open when reading/compiling it as soon as it encounters the [`__DATA__`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) section. See the section on `__DATA__` in perldata, where this behaviour is described.

The approach of closing the filehandle is documented there as well.